# Making a replica in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a replica in mongodb. I have used the following commands to make a replica. I got the following outputs.

```
 cfg = { _id : "mySet", members : [ { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27017" 
 } ] }    
 rs.initiate(cfg)
```

Output:

```
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Attempting to initiate a replica set with name mySet, but command line reports 0; rejecting",
"code" : 93,
"codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig"
}
```

i get the following output:

```
017-09-22T14:22:22.093+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: conf is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

When i ran show dbs and rs.config(), i get the following errors:

```
show dbs
2017-09-22T14:23:56.234+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases 
failed:{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
"code" : 13435,
"codeName" : "NotMasterNoSlaveOk"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 . 
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:62:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:769:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:659:15 .  
@(shellhelp2):1:1

> rs.config()
2017-09-22T14:24:23.718+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Could not 
retrieve replica set config: {
"info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
"code" : 94,
"codeName" : "NotYetInitialized"
} :
rs.conf@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1276:11
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231434/3-node-mongo-db-authentication-setup-fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete all replication and oplog.

```
use local
db.dropDatabase()
```

restart the mongo

```
config = {_id: "repl1", members:[
{_id: 0, host: 'localhost:15000'},
{_id: 1, host: '192.168.2.100:15000'}]
}
rs.initiate(config);
```